# How do I make the args function equal to 2? As it is just throwing File Not found exception

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, args

```
/**
  *   Compilation  : javac Traversal.java
  *   Execution    : java Traversal args0 ----- GraphicsMode
  *                : java Traversal args0 args1 ----- TextMode
  *
  *   Arguments    : args0 - boardfilename.txt
  *                     args1 - movesfilename.txt
  *
  *   Controls     : h - left movement
  *                  l - right movement
  *                  j - down movement
  *                  k - up movement
  **/   
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            GameBoard board = Middleware.parseArgs(args[0]);
            Middleware.validateBoard(board);
            GraphicsMode.play(board);
        }else if (args.length == 2) {
            GameBoard board = Middleware.parseArgs(args[0]);
            Middleware.validateBoard(board);
            String moves = Middleware.readMoves(new Scanner(new File(args[1])));
            TextMode.play(board, moves);
        }
        exit();
    }

    /**
    * Sleep for 4000 microseconds to allow
    * the final event sound to finish
    * playing and then exits.
    */
    public static void exit() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: `args` is not a function, it's the command line arguments typed when starting the program. And `FileNotFoundException` means it can't find the file you are specifying. Simple as that.

Comment: The file that I am trying to open is in my src file though so it should open?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not in the code you posted, but somehow within the code where it is looking for some file.  Read the exception, what is the cause?  Use absolute file paths to determine the path.

Comment: *The file that I am trying to open is in my src file though so it should open?* **No**. Not unless you run your program in the src folder. Or you specify the full path to the file. Java does not "search source folder for files I want to read".

Comment: @ggb667 There is no exception. When i execute it, it just exits with code 0.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am running it in the src folder though.

Comment: @SeanRaffaelli *As it is just throwing File Not found exception* - *There is no exception. When i execute it, it just exits with code 0.* - **what** are you asking?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There is a board File and a moves file thatIi want to input and read however I don't know where to input the file name and directory. I am trying to edit this post and add the other java file however stack overflow is not allowing me to do so.

Comment: How are you running the **program**? Also, I already told you, you specify the path to the files when you the run the **program**. I don't know how you are doing so, and I don't know where your files are, but something like `java -cp . Traversal "c:\YOUR DIRECTORY\boardfilename.txt" "c:\YOUR DIRECTORY\movesfilename.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in your JavaDoc, you need to run this program from the command prompt (cmd window) as follows if you want two arguments to be passed to the program:

```
java Traversal args0 args1
```

where

```
args0 - boardfilename.txt                  
args1 - movesfilename.txt
```

In other words, run it as `java Traversal boardfilename.txt movesfilename.txt` from the command prompt. If `boardfilename.txt` and `movesfilename.txt` are not in the same location where `Traversal.class` is, mention their complete paths i.e.

```
java Traversal path-to-boardfilename.txt path-to-movesfilename.txt
```

If you are running it in eclipse, right-click **Traversal.java** > Click **Run Configurations...** > Put the values in the dialog box as shown in the screenshot > Click **Run**

[image]

In this case (i.e. when you are trying to run it from eclipse), make sure `boardfilename.txt` and `movesfilename.txt` are there in the parent folder of `src`.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand.

Comment: I've added a screenshot. I hope, it helps.